# Fast approximation for bivariate normal cumulative distribution function

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

The cdf of a normal distribution has some nice approximations like
$$F(x) = 1/(1 + \exp(-0.07056 x^3 – 1.5976 x)),$$
see https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/188388/1/v02-i01-p114_60-313-1-PB.pdf

Is there something similar for a bivariate normal distribution function? I am looking for a fast approximation in the sense of compute runtime. The approximation does not need to be the most exact, so errors in the order of 10% are completely fine.
The use case is that I need to integrate a bivariate normal distribution over multiple small rectangles.

Comment: Is this for an arbitrary bivariate normal or can we make assumptions about the correlation and relative variances of the variables? Also, how much overhead on precalculating parameters are you OK with?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot make assumptions about their correlation or variances. Precalculating parameters once and using it for multiple integrals is fine. It is also a good fine if we use a function that has similar shape as a bivariate normal. As long as it is bell shaped in 2d and we can control the shape with a 2x2 correlation matrix, it is fine.